# How do I add and use Chrome Extensions with Cypress.io?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cypress

I'm currently dealing with a an X-Frame-Options issue being blocked when running my Cypress.io tests.  I cannot change the server setup to modify the X-Frame settings.  Somebody mentioned to me that I should try a chrome extension called "Ignore X-Frame headers."

I have the extension installed on my non-Cypress Chrome, but how do I install it for use in my Cypress.io tests?  If I go into developer tools while running a Cypress test, I can see that no extensions are loaded for Cypress/Chrome.

Any ideas on how or IF I can do this?  I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to install the extension through Cypress chrome (and enable it).

Comment: Thank you! What a simple thing to do, I just didn't even bother to even consider this.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on how to do this?

Comment: For those that are confused. Open the cypress chrome page (but running one of your specs), go to `chrome://extensions`, *enable* `developer mode`, `Load Unpacked`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `before:browser:launch` event to load a Chrome extension.

More information on how to use this event [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Usage).

Answer (score 2):

For those wondering what the link is to that extension is:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe

paste that link into the chrome window Cypress is running in and install it then try to re-load your test. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
const path = require("path")
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
    // supply the absolute path to an unpacked extension's folder
    // NOTE: extensions cannot be loaded in headless Chrome
    launchOptions.extensions.push(path.resolve(__dirname,"../../extension_name"))

    return launchOptions
  })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).